# Turkish character reading on Windows console

Tags: c, encoding, character-encoding, scanf

I need to input Turkish characters from console in C. But I can't. This code working.

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Turkish");
printf("ü ğ ı ş ç ö");
```

Output: `ü ğ ı ş ç ö`

But when I try to use, it don't working.

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Turkish");
scanf("%c %c %c %c", c, (c + 1), (c + 2), (c + 3));
printf("%c %c %c %c", *c, *(c + 1), *(c + 2), *(c + 3));
```

Input: `ğ ü ş ç`

Output: `§ ? Y ┼`

My operating system is Windows. When I read a file characters, there is not problem. But only console inputs are problem. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needs a command in cmd for solution of this problem. I solved. Just before program execution, command `chcp 1254`, then console can input Turkish characters.